# Capacitor in AC op-amps

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, capacitor, circuit-analysis, amplifier

[image]

Need clarification on why is a capacitor connected in AC op-amps but not in DC? And what does this capacitor do?

Comment: Hi, welcome, and thank you for your question. This is called AC coupling, which blocks the DC component of the signal. Would you mind editing your post to explain any specific questions that you have about this technique?

Comment: Yep, this is a homework-style / learning material question, and it really wouldn't be useful if we just copied the whole material you've read up to this point; if you didn't understand it so far, doing that wouldn't even help you. Because this is a problem we can't solve for you, we can't really help you. Please describe what exactly you're not clear about.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because homework needs an attempt at a solution

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment, and it might provide an answer for you.

In order to answer your question, we need to know what you do know, and don't understand, so here is a series of questions for you to answer.

In the DC-coupled amplifier, what are the opamp node voltages and output voltage when

a) Vin is 0 V?
b) Vin is 1 V?
c) Vin switches between +/- 1 V?
d) Vin switches between +5 V and +3 V?

In the AC coupled amplifier, what are the opamp node voltages, capacitor voltage, and output voltage when

a) Vin is 0 V?
b) Vin is 1 V?
c) Vin switches between +/- 1 V...
c1) switching slow enough for the capacitor to charge fully?
c2) switching so fast the voltage on the capacitor does not change?
d) Vin switches between +5 V and +3 V...
d1) switching slow enough for the capacitor to charge fully?
d2) switching so fast the voltage on the capacitor does not change?

When we know which of these you have trouble answering, we can can help you. However, you might just answer it yourself working through these.

Answer (score 0):

The capacitor not only blocks the DC componenet of the input signal. More than that, it determines the DC feedback of the amplifier - and this might be very important.

- The DC gain of the amplifier is only **Adc=1** (100% feedback)
- For AC (frequency sufficiently above the corner frequency of the input highpass effect) the gain is **Acl=-RF/R1**.

As a consequence, any DC offset (appearing as an unwanted parasitic input voltage) will be amplified with "1" only (and NOT with RF/R1).

Therefore, the AC gain can be made very large without considering DC offset effects.